# unfamiliar with php and need to fix validation errors

Tags: wordpress, validation

From the Validation site, there are few errors on my site that I would like to fix.  What's the best way to approach this?

I am not familiar with php at all.  Is there a way to do it all in CSS? If I needed to know php, where is a good place to start?

Is there a plugin I can use that can help?  (I currently have w3cache and have read some people suggest using that.)

Comment: If you post some of the errors and code that's causing them, you could get help.

Comment: Error: Stray end tag main.

From line 134, column 47; to line 134, column 53

/article> </main></div>

Warning: The contentinfo role is unnecessary for element footer.

From line 136, column 40; to line 137, column 54

iv></div> <footer↩id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo" ><div↩c

Error: Stray end tag div.

From line 150, column 46; to line 150, column 51

 </footer></div><div↩s